# Find highest frequent element (the smallest one if possible) and its occurrences in integer array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, integer, find-occurrences

Problems: Find ***2*** things

- The **highest occurrence** in an **given unsorted integer array**
- The **element** that has the highest occurrence and **if** there are **more than one element satisfy** (have the **same highest occurrence**) the result is the **smallest** element.

Please solve the problems simple as possible, don't use pointers or any advanced containers like hashtable, pair or map (I'm rather beginner)

For example:

```
{1, 2, 8, 2, 5, 0, 5}
```

The answer is 2 and 2 (Element `2` and `5` both occur twice but `2` is the smallest)

Here is the code but it only finds the highest occurrence right.

```
int A[] = {1, 2, 8, 2, 5, 0, 5};
int N = 7;
    int maxCount = 0;
    int minMode = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <= N - 1; i++) {
           int count = 0;
           for (int j = 0; j <= N - 1; j++) {
             if (A[i] == A[j])
                 count++;
       }
      if (count >= maxCount)
        {
            maxCount = count;
            minMode = A[i];
        }

     }
        cout << maxCount << " " << minMode << endl;
```

Comment: using a map isnt really "advanced", rather using a `std::map` makes it as simple as it can be.

Comment: We have a bit of a language problem here: what is the difference between "the highest occurrence" and "the element that has the highest occurrence" ?

Comment: @idclev obviously, this is some sort of homework or test, where this requirement is included in order to ensure that all participants are playing on an equal ground and that they do actually understand how to solve the problem without using some ready-made facility that does all the work for them by magic without them understanding how it works.

Comment: @MikeNakis thats speculations. OP clearly states that map is to be avoided because they consider it as "advanced" and want a "simple" solution. That premise is wrong, because using a map **is** simple. If it is a hard requirement it should be stated in the question

Comment: @MikeNakis really appreciate but can you suggest editting it?

Comment: @idclev463035818 tks, anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is O(n), but without using structures, it becomes O(n²).

Here's a simple O(n²) solution:

```
int main(){    
    int A[7] = {1, 2, 8, 2, 5, 0, 5};
    int value, occurrences;
    int maxValue = 99999999, maxOccurrences = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++){
        value = A[i]; occurrences = 0;
        for(int j = 0; j < 7; j++) if(A[j] == value) occurrences++;
        if(occurrences > maxOccurrences){
            maxValue = value; maxOccurrences = occurrences;
        }
        else if(occurrences == maxOccurrences){
            if(value < maxValue) {
                maxValue = value; 
                maxOccurrences = occurrences; 
            }
        }       
    }
    cout<<maxValue<<" occurs "<<maxOccurrences<<" times"<<endl;
}
```

We initialize maxValue being a very large number, just to help the fact that if two numbers occur the same number of times, the lowest will be the chosen.

Then we just iterate and count.

A possible optimization is: suppose you are searching for 5 in the array. Always you find a 5, add the occurrence to the amount and set the array value to -1, so when you eventually start from it, you know it is -1 and you can skip that element.

Comment: but why maxValue is initialized with a big value

Comment: Because it makes it easier to store the smallest value. You can start with any value, it's not a big deal.